# Public Key Scheme decryption.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves, cryptography, elliptic-functions

You have been sent a message based on the following Public Key Scheme.
1) Bob chooses two large primes $\ p,q $ with $ p \equiv q \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and computes $ n=pq. $
2) Bob chooses integers $ e,d $ with $ ed \equiv 1 $(mod lcm($p+1,q+1). $ (He could use $ (p+1)(q+1) $ instead of $ lcm(p+1,q+1). $ ) And makes $ n $ and $ e $ public.
3) Alice represents her message as a pair of integers $ (m_{1},m_{2}) \pmod n. $  She regards $ (m_{1},m_{2})$ as a point $M$ on the elliptic curve $E$ given by $y^2 = x^3 + b \pmod n, $ where $ b=m_{2} ^2 -m_{1} ^3 \pmod n$ (she does not need to compute $b$).

4) Alice adds $M$ to itself $e$ times on $E$ to obtain $C=(c_{1} ,c_{2} )= eM$ and sends C to Bob.

5)Bob computes $M=dC$ on $E$ to obtain $M$.

Using the described method, and given you have public key $n=9986899671513153299302129148204573775860428310315984346586760515456471532627966903385948703$, encryption integer $e=141597355687225811174313690501511542123673874802409558365796639534962049206893437498331243$ and your secret decryption integer is $d=2037035976334486086268445688409378161051468395093183943342100330412667269212831842566144003$ decode the message $[7702619106292151978427151476214069077485335286048205301635368880467359865152659693199602473, 
4357595334666159972997284171164257443639580965587791255697825733007347880407380846464584605 ].$

Comment: If you don't know how to solve it, you didn't need to reply.  I posted this here in hopes that someone who does know how or understands it better than I will assist me to better understand what to do.

Comment: Well the work I've done on it so far just finished, which was factoring n into the values of p and q.  After letting magma run for about 2 hours it finally got me that p=1709182199829390319430546800769286081505891080736007445463793027778086882296029622221266562, q=5668719286381552419984715204874228547770892010926452861246265676949151369089474791098182668.

Comment: Breaking d down into binary to allow for successive squaring has that $ d=2^0 +2^1 +2^{150} + 2^{300} $

Comment: I think the final answer is $M=[5744706834952992316134105121212226909095937404184252640388106909798665712652416109994033624, 511382955095951190601723938279853992465650408691718508793908750457187964716236388538694763].$

Comment: No, b is not given but it is stated that it is undeeded.  Also, I did make a mistake in step 2, it is $ed$ not $e,d$.

Comment: Well we are given n, e, and d.  To calculate M, I changed d into binary format, then used successive squaring mod n since the elliptic curve is mod n.

Comment: Yes, the p and q I calculated do multiply to n.

Comment: Yes, M is split into $ M=(m_{1}, m_{2})$ and then added to itself e times to get $ C=(c_{1} , c_{2})=eM$

Comment: What do you mean by the d having ones at 1, 151300301?  My professor told me I should turn d into a binary representation of itself, which is $ 2^0*2^1*2^{150}*2^{300} $ and then multiply $M=dC$ using successive squaring.

Comment: Well, using $n=667$, $d=37$ and $C=(13,527)$ first I'd factor 37 into its binary components, giving $2^0*2^2*2^5$ then I would take $13*2^0 \pmod{667}=13, 13*2^2 \pmod{667}=52, 13*2^5 \pmod{667}=416$ then take $13*52 \pmod{667}=9, 9*416 \pmod{667} =409$ then I would do the same thing for the 527 and get 195.

Comment: I can't say I'm familiar with what you are suggesting, no.

Comment: Yes, I do see how that would get 13M.  How does that translate to being used for decoding M?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how $d(c_{1},c_{2})$ is supposed to be calculated if its not in the method I used earlier.  If the d from the problem factors into $ 2^0, 2^1, 2^{150}, 2^{300} $ what does this translate into for point doubling?

Comment: Do elliptic points not add like normal points?  I'm using magma, but I'm not very familiar with the language used for it nor how I would have it add elliptic points.  100 in binary is $2^2*2^5*2^6$

Comment: It looks like the highest power of 2 relates to how many 2's are in the point doubling formula, and relate somewhat to where the $+P$ or $+M$ are located.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very familiar with magma either, nor any of the other software that is used for this.  For me to do this, I would need to calculate most of it by hand then just type the last part (with the 300 2's) into magma.

Comment: So, for the purpose of the point doubling, given that d factors into those powers of 2 mentioned, would that mean I need to solve $2(M+2^149(M+2^148(M+2M)))+M$ ?  (Also I am heading off to work, I won't be able to make any more replies for about 9.5 hours.  Thank you so much for your help so far, and I hope you can continue to assist me later.)

Comment: Not sure why this was put on hold, the OP has done a great deal of work as can be witnessed from the comments. Only has one slight issue for solving. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually the Elliptic Curve version of the Koyama, Maurer, Okamoto and Vanstone ([*KMOV*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/427.pdf)) cryptosystem.

Note that the formulas for the addition law on $E_n (0, b)$ never use the value of $b$. Therefore, Bob nevers need to compute it, but he can compute it if he wants as $b = c^2_2 −c^3_1 \pmod n$ (just like Alice had no need).

What is important in this schema is having an algorithm that implements the idea of
repeated doubling and addition for computing the decryption that is given by $dP$, where $P$ is the point of interest on the elliptic curve. You have:

$$d = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^{150} + 2^{300}$$

This would give:

$$M = dC = 2^0C + 2^1C + 2^{150}C + 2^{300}C$$

At this point, just use your favorite CAS like Magma, SAGE, Maxima, GAP, GP/PARI, ... to do this heavy lifting for the [*point additions and multiplications*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication). For example, see [*GP/PARI*](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Functions_related_to_elliptic_curves.html) and an [*example*](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_arithmetic#PARI.2FGP). It also looks like you are using Magma and it appears to have extensive support for elliptic curves, see [*Magma Elliptic Curves*](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/elliptic_curves) (look at the **Operations on Points - Arithmetic** link).

We are given:

**n**

$ n = 9986899671513153299302129148204573775860428310315984346586760515456471532627966903385948703$

**Encryption integer**

$e=141597355687225811174313690501511542123673874802409558365796639534962049206893437498331243$

**Secret decryption integer**

$d=2037035976334486086268445688409378161051468395093183943342100330412667269212831842566144003$

We are asked to decode the message $C = (c_1, c_2)$, where

$C = (c_1, c_2) = (7702619106292151978427151476214069077485335286048205301635368880467359865152659693199602473, 
4357595334666159972997284171164257443639580965587791255697825733007347880407380846464584605)$

So, on $E$, we would get:

$M = dC =\\ (1916011819050209140118251805161805, 1905142001200915140919211905062112)$

Note: We should be able to use this result of $M$ with $e$ and generate $C$. Indeed, we get:

$C = eM = (7702619106292151978427151476214069077485335286048205301635368880467359865152659693199602473, 4357595334666159972997284171164257443639580965587791255697825733007347880407380846464584605)$

For the record:

$b = c_2^2 - c_1^3 \pmod n= m_2^2 - m_1^3 \pmod n = 5445330577961766747015463565087337781248624265142396436595877867192503947685106526655274667$

Comment: Awesome, Amzoti!

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you so much for your help Amzoti, you've been a huge help and I really appreciate everything you've done to help me not only solve but also understand the question and how to solve it.